# Check current receiver status before sending notification

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app has two sets of users (Sellers and buyers). A seller can logout from the same device and can login as a buyer. I was quite successful in sending notification between these sets of users using FCM by collecting the specific device tokens. Now I am encountering a problem. Since a buyer can be seller in the same device , a notification intended to a seller is delivering to him even if he logged as BUYER , as device token same in two instants. I had considered topic messaging instead , but but from documents I understand that only 1000 notification per topic can be send at a time, it is not feasible for my application
The solution is that I like to check whether the Receiver status (currently he is buyer or sender) before sending notification. Currently he is buyer or seller not the previous status.  How can we able to check receiver current status prior to sending notification? is there is a way ?

Below code shows my method for sending notification and image shows my database structure. In image it can be seen that User (buyer) and seller have same device token

```
    void sendNotification(String name, String enquiry, String token){
    try {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("title","You have an Enquiry from: "+ name);
        data.put("body", enquiry);
        JSONObject notificationData =new JSONObject();
        notificationData.put("notification",data);
        notificationData.put("to",token);


        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, notificationData
                , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                Toast.makeText(SendEnquiryActivity.this,"Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(SendEnquiryActivity.this,error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                HashMap<String,String> map =new HashMap<>();

                String key ="Key=//my key here";
                map.put("Authorization",key);
                map.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                return map;
            }
        };

        queue.add(request);


    }catch (Exception ex){

    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxyZ4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Bot..added code in question